# Video compression tools

Tags: windows, file-compression, video-recording

I am using a software - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/screen-recorder-lite/9mvbdsj392f2#activetab=pivot:overviewtab 
for recording audio and video. It's a screen recorder for windows. 
But it creates really big files. A 10 min video recording is 200 MB.
Are there any good tools that could compress the video by reducing some video 
the quality or audio quality? As its a big file I am looking for something 
that I can install locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible tool if [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). [Here](https://superuser.com/a/4252/409497) you can find good explanation how to recode the video file. Here is extract from answer:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4
```

Be moderate as every compression introduce (more or less) artefacts in the image.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the reply by `Romeo Ninov` the most popular, open source and configurable tool for converting media (video, but also images and audio) is ffmpeg

If you are not familiar with CLI ("Command Line Interface" meaning to be used via command line terminal) software but prefer it with GUI ("Graphical User Interface") there are some popular ones that are based on and use ffmpeg for processing.

For example:

- [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/)
- [Vidcoder](https://vidcoder.net/)

If, on the other hand, you prefer a more advanced and configurable GUI program that is free and does not use ffmpeg for processing, may I suggest
[Hybrid](https://www.selur.de/)

In your use case, I can inform you that a screen recording tool is already included in Windows 10, found in the Xbox Game Bar, which you can access with the `Win+G` key combination.
In the settings (top gear) you can choose the audio source you want to record.

On the other hand, if you are willing to use a more professional and configurable tool, I suggest [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) which is also open-source and allows you to choose in the settings also the format and encoder to be used for the file.

I remind you that directly encoding the source with different settings is a preferable choice than re-encoding an already encoded file since in most cases lossy encodings are used so each encoding corresponds to a variable loss of quality (how much depends on the settings chosen and the specific content of the file).